# change values in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key, key-value-store

I have my dictionary set up. now im just wondering how to change the values in each keys ?
I know that dictionaries are mutable so I should be able to change them, I just don't know how. 
lets say if the user enters a1 = "x" it should assign the value of "x" to the key [0] and update the printing.

```
board = {0:' ', 1:' ', 2:' ',
         3:' ', 4:' ', 5:' ',
         6:' ', 7:' ', 8:' ',
        }

print("    " "a" "   " "b" "   " "c")
print("  ""-------------")
print(("1"),("|"),board[0],"|",board[1], "|" ,board[2], "|")
print("  ""-------------")
print(("2"),("|"),board[3],"|",board[4], "|" ,board[5], "|")
print("  ""-------------")   
print(("3"),("|"),board[6],"|",board[7], "|" ,board[8], "|")
print("  ""-------------")
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign the value `value` to the key `key`,

```
board[key] = value
```

Why is this a dict, though? This looks like a job for a list, maybe a nested list.

Comment: probably, but I couldn't figure out how to print out the board using lists! 
how would you implement it with nested list anyways?

Comment: With a flat list, you could print it exactly the way you're doing right now. (There would be better ways, but what you're doing would work.) With a nested list, it'd be initialized as `board = [[' ']*3 for i in xrange(3)]`, and you'd access row 1, column 2 with `board[1][2]`.